# OCMockito capturing primitive types?

Tags: ocmockito

How do I use OCMockito to capture argument with primitive values?

MKTArgumentCaptor seems to be able to capture only object types? Xcode says "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For primitive arguments, you have to do a little dance. Let's say we mocked NSMutableArray and wanted to verify calls to

```
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;
```

Instead of

```
[verify(mockArray) replaceObjectAtIndex:[argument capture] withObject:anything()];
```

which gives you the type conflict, we just have a dummy value (0 will do fine) but add an OCMockito call to override the matcher at a given argument index:

```
[[verify(mockArray) withMatcher:[argument capture] forArgument:0]
    replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:anything()];
```

The argument index for `-withMatcher:forArgument:` is 0-based for the first argument, so this says, "For the first argument, ignore whatever was passed in and use this matcher instead."

There is also a method `-withMatcher:` which just does this on the first argument, so this example could be simplified to

```
[[verify(mockArray) withMatcher:[argument capture]]
    replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:anything()];
```

Comment: [argument value] then returns a NSNumber.

Comment: That's correct. You then take that NSNumber and ask it whatever you want.