# OCMockito anything() for primitive types

Tags: objective-c, ocmockito

For method signature

```
- (void)insertValue:(NSUInteger)value;
```

I'm trying to see if insertValue for any value never gets called.

```
[verifyCount(test, never()) insertValue:0];
```

Since compiler complains anything() primitive types, how do I test this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just like https://stackoverflow.com/a/20524472/246895

```
[[verifyCount(test, never()) withMatcher:anything()]
    insertValue:0];
```

OCMockito does all argument checking using OCHamcrest matchers. Normally, OCMockito turns a primitive argument into an NSNumber, then wraps it in an implicit OCHamcrest `equalTo` matcher. But `-withMatcher:` and `-withMatcher:forArgument` replace the implicit matcher.