# OCMockito Unit testing - how to verify that a method with primitive has been called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmockito

**How can I verify that my mock object created with OCMockito has received a method invocation with a primitive argument?**

The method that I'm trying to test is `setProgress:(float)progress`

```
    CompositeProgressView* mockProgress = mock([CompositeProgressView class]);
    self.downloader.progressView = mockProgress;
//run a task that increments progress
...
//test
    [verify(mockProgress) setProgress:anything()]; //does not work
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OCMockito anything() for primitive types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562059/ocmockito-anything-for-primitive-types)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[verify(mockProgress) withMatcher:anything()] setProgress:0];
```

A described in "How do you specify matchers for primitive arguments?" at https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito.

Hope that helps!