# Verify that correct frame is set on subview

Tags: ios, ocmockito

**Intro**

I'd like to test that the right frame is set on a views subview (which is injected as a mock).

However I can't seem to find a way to verify that the right CGRect is set

**Current Attempt**

```
-(void)testThatCorrectFrameIsSet {
  //Arrange
  MKTArgumentCaptor *argumentCaptor = [[MKTargumentCaptor alloc] init];
  self.sut.subView = mock([UIView class]);

  //Act
  [self.sut awakeFromNib];

  //Assert
  [[[MKTVerify(self.sut.subView) withMatcher:[argumentCaptor capture]] setFrame:CGSizeZero];

  expect([argumentCaptor.value CGRectValue].size.x).to.beCloseToWithin(42, 0.001);
}
```

**What's going wrong**

I get:

```
"NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[_NSInlineData CGRectValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7af325c0"
```

Which makes me wonder how to correctly capture CGRect values

**Side Note**

I am aware of the fact that I could inject an actual UIView instead of a mocked one, however the actual code I'm testing prevents me from doing this for reasons that would make this question harder than needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use 'CGRectZero' instead of 'CGSizeZero', but this doesn't solve the Problem.

It looks like the captor value is not an NSValue.

```
//Arrange
MKTArgumentCaptor *argumentCaptor = [[MKTArgumentCaptor alloc] init];
UIView* subView = mock([UIView class]);

// Act
[subView setFrame:CGRectMake(1, 2, 3, 4)];

//Assert
[[MKTVerify(subView) withMatcher:[argumentCaptor capture]] setFrame:CGRectZero];

NSValue* capturedValue = [argumentCaptor value];
if (![capturedValue isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Captured value is no NSValue!");
}
```

Hope this helps to track down the problem.

Comment: Thanks, you were right on the CGRectZero part. However I know the captors value is not NSValue, how to get them is what i'm trying to find out :)

Comment: In this case an int is stored as a NSNumber, but I couldn't find anything about CGRect.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511562/ocmockito-capturing-primitive-types

Comment: Those should be stored in NSValue ;)